# Core data strange crash while getting the persistent coordinator

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

There seems to be an issue with core data. The app is getting crash while getting a persistent coordinator for iOS 10 mobile.

The crash is:-

> Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=File at path does not appear to be a SQLite database: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35630A3E-0697-4244-929F-90F35DD1167E/Library/Application Support/Quickride.sqlite, NSSQLiteErrorDomain=26}

I have tried finding a solution related to core data corruption issue. But there was no solution. I guess this issue with persistent coordinator getting corrupted.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Quickride")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().log.debug("Url : \(String(describing: url))")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
                    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: false]
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: mOptions)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject

        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "QuickRide domain", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        self.log.debug("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
    }
    return coordinator
}()
```

Here is the crash report of the crash:-

```
 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
 0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x21b4a4c specialized _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 27869
 1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x204f693 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 113116
 2  Quickride                      0x3e8795 closure #1 in closure #1 in AppDelegate.persistentContainer.getter (AppDelegate.swift:633)
 3  Quickride                      0x6ff2bd thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed NSPersistentStoreDescription, @guaranteed Error?) -> () (<compiler-generated>)
 4  CoreData                       0x1ea637c1 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithDescription:completionHandler:] + 406
 5  CoreData                       0x1eb05e4b -[NSPersistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:] + 398
 6  Quickride                      0x3e7d13 AppDelegate.persistentContainer.getter (<compiler-generated>)
 7  Quickride                      0x146b4f specialized static UserCoreDataHelper.getUserObject() (CoreDataHelper.swift:17)
 8  Quickride                      0x4c2487 AppStartupHandler.performSessionInitializationTask() (<compiler-generated>)
 9  Quickride                      0x3e6ee5 AppDelegate.handleUserNotification(newUserNotification:) (<compiler-generated>)
10 Quickride                      0x3e6a1b AppDelegate.processRemoteNotification(userInfo:) (<compiler-generated>)
11 Quickride                      0x3ee493 specialized AppDelegate.application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) (AppDelegate.swift:394)
12 Quickride                      0x3e6717 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) (<compiler-generated>)
13 Quickride                      0x7fe83d FCM_swizzle_appDidReceiveRemoteNotificationWithHandler (FIRMessagingRemoteNotificationsProxy.m:504)
14 UIKit                          0x21ed2927 -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 5066
15 UIKit                          0x21ebf001 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 5168
16 UIKit                          0x21ec3c1d -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1640
17 UIKit                          0x21ed67c5 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3149 + 40
18 UIKit                          0x21ec135b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 142
19 FrontBoardServices             0x1e2fcc13 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 18
20 FrontBoardServices             0x1e2fcacd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 220
21 FrontBoardServices             0x1e2fcdb7 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 44
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1c9d7fdd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1c9d7b05 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 424
24 CoreFoundation                 0x1c9d5f51 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
25 CoreFoundation                 0x1c9291af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
26 CoreFoundation                 0x1c928fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
27 UIKit                          0x21cb6e2d -[UIApplication _run] + 660
28 UIKit                          0x21cb1a53 UIApplicationMain +   150
29 Quickride                      0x7ef45 main (A ppDelegate.swift:31)
30 libdyld.dylib                  0x1c1164eb start + 2
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you make a change (even a minor one) to your model?

Comment: @Magnas I had some changes to my model earlier

Comment: Did you already try deleting and re-installing the app? If you made a model change, you may need to write migration code, if it was a change that cannot be handled by auto-migration.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise with the terminology, it is not the persistent store *coordinator* but the persistent store *file* which is corrupt.  To confirm this, run Terminal.app and try to open with the sqlite3 command line tool:

`sqlite3 /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35630A3E-0697-4244-929F-90F35DD1167E/Library/Application Support/Quickride.sqlite`

If you get the same error, you've got a corrupt file.  If you are developing an app, trash the file and move on. If the file contains data that you actually need, hope you've got a prior backup that works.